Drawing on first row and first column in nicematrix

An arrow is drawn from 1-|1 to node 5-|5 (i.e., southeast of cell 4-4).
I think it should be possible to draw from 0-|0 (node for first row and first column) to 6-|6 (node for last row and last column), but tikz-pgf throws an error when we say
\draw[color=IndianRed1] (0-|0) -- ([xshift=-1pt] 5-|5);
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[first-row, last-row, first-col, last-col, nullify-dots, margin]
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &        \\
         L_1   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & L_{1}  \\
        \Vdots & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & \Vdots \\ \hline
               & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &        \\
         L_4   & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & L_{4}  \\
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &
        \CodeAfter
        \begin{tikzpicture}[arrows={-Latex[]}]
            \draw[color=IndianRed1] (1-|1) -- ([xshift=-1pt] 5-|5);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


Please show not only one code line for the error case, but a complete example. → I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?.

And also show the error message, best as code copy from the log-file

Yes. When first-row is in force, there is no node called 0. It's unlikely that there will be such node in a future version of nicematrix (for technical reason). The solution suggested by cabobah is the best one.

If I understand correctly, what you want, you can use a NiceArray and \SubMatrix:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{rcc|ccl}[nullify-dots,margin]
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &        \\
         L_1   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & L_{1}  \\
        \Vdots & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & \Vdots \\ \cline{2-5}
               & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &        \\
         L_4   & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & L_{4}  \\
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &
   \CodeAfter
   \SubMatrix{(}{2-2}{5-5}{)}       
   \begin{tikzpicture}[arrows={-Latex[]}]
     \draw[color=IndianRed1] (1-|1)-- ([xshift=-1pt] 7-|7);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{rcc|ccl}[nullify-dots,margin]
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &        \\
         L_1   & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & L_{1}  \\
        \Vdots & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & \Vdots \\ \cline{2-5}
               & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} &        \\
         L_4   & a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & L_{4}  \\
               & C_{1}  & \Cdots &        & C_4    &
   \CodeAfter
   \SubMatrix{(}{2-2}{5-5}{)}       
   \tikz[arrows={-Latex[]}]
     \draw[color=IndianRed1] (1-|1)-- ([xshift=-1pt] last);
   \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

Both with the same result:

